# VirtualBox上のDebian9で、eth0がなく、sshができない。

Tags: virtualbox, debian

Mac上のVirtualBoxのDebian9で、ネットワークを構築しようとしています。

[image: VirtualBoxでのネットワークの設定はこちら]

> アダプター1 NAT
>   アダプター2 ホストオンリーアダプタ vboxnet0

設定はこのようになっています。

以前別のネットワークの設定を流用しようと思い、
以下の設定を書きました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> allow-hotplug eth0
>   auto eth0
>   iface eth0 inet dhcp
>
> allow-hotplug eth1
>   auto eth1
>   iface eth1 int static
>   address 192.168.33.15
>   network 192.168.33.0
>   netmask 255.255.255.0
>   broadcast 192.168.33.255

以前の環境(Kali Linux)では、こちらでうまく動きました。
そこで今回はこれにならい、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

> auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> allow-hotplug enp0s3
>   auto enp0s3
>   iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
>
> allow-hotplug enp0s3
>   auto enp0s3
>   iface enp0s3 int static
>   address 192.168.33.17
>   network 192.168.33.0
>   netmask 255.255.255.0

このように書きました。
今回でそれがうまくいきません。

`route`を見てみると、
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このようになります。
ネットワークへの疎通はできている(ping 8.8.8.8は通る)のですが、ホストからのsshができません。
ifconfigをしても、設定したアドレスが割り振られず、以下のようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

どうやらネットワークインターフェースとして、eth0,eth1がなく、enp0s3,enp0s8というもののみがあるようです。

一応、[Ubuntu 16.04 LTSにしたらeth0がなくなっていた件について](https://qiita.com/mharada/items/d31fb959124e337c78f9)
ここら辺を見ては見ましたが、解決できませんでした。どなたか正しいinterfacesの形をお教え願えませんでしょうか。

Comment: 後から検索する人のためにも設定やエラーメッセージは画像ではなく本文内に直接書いていただけると助かります。

Comment: 確かに。ご指摘ありがとうございます。修正いたします。

Answer (score 2):

解決いたしました。お騒がせいたしました。

`# cat /etc/network/interfaces`

> # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
>   # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
>
> source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
>
> # The loopback network interface
>   auto lo
>   iface lo inet loopback
>
> allow-hotplug enp0s3
>   auto enp0s3
>   iface enp0s3 inet dhcp
>
> allow-hotplug enp0s8
>   auto enp0s8
>   iface enp0s8 inet static
>   address 192.168.33.17
>   network 192.168.33.0
>   netmask 255.255.255.0
>   broadcast 192.168.33.255

以上の設定で解決いたしました。